# Deferred shading

Tags: opengl, rendering

I'm thinking about implementing a deferred renderer and have a some questions.
Specs:
OpenGL 3.0, maximally 3 render targets, must support specular exponent, emissive exponent.

1. Is the difference between storing normal components in 8bit vs 16bit noticeable?
2. Is 24bit (linear) depth component accurate enough for outdoor scenes?
3. Which g-buffer configuration to use (g-buffer size vs parameter reconstruction)?

**Option 1**: 32bit color depth, requires position reconstruction from depth and normal Z reconstruction from normal X,Y, but is smaller
RT1: 24 depth; 8 material index (is there a texture format that I can use like this?)
RT2: 16 normX; 16 normY
RT3: 8 red; 8 green; 8 blue; 7 specular exponent, 1 emisseve (packed)

**Option 2**: 64bit color depth, no reconstruction, but is twice as big and has some wasted room (rgb and material index)
RT1: 16 posX; 16 posY; 16 posZ; 16 material index
RT2: 16 normX; 16 normY; 16 normZ; 16 specular exponent
RT3: 16 red; 16 green; 16 blue; 16 emissive exponent

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Performance vs size is not a decision you should make now and enforce for all users for all time. It's very likely that cards now, and almost certain that cards later, will make the larger version just as fast. Better to set as an option and let users select perf vs quality.

Comment: I removed the unrelated questions.

Comment: Regarding performance: I would just like to know if there's some obvious advantage of doing it either way. If not then I'll implement both and compare them.

Comment: "OpenGL 2.0" Is that OpenGL ***ES*** 2.0, or desktop GL 2.0? Because there's really no point in restricting yourself to 2.0 when all 2.0 hardware also supports 2.1.

Comment: The desktop version and yes I can change it to OpenGL 2.1 even though I don't think it introduced anything important for my purposes.

Comment: Add to what Nicol Bolas said that you probably don't want OpenGL 2.1 either, because it's a nightmare for a deferred renderer. If you settle for 3.0 and up, you have a lot less trouble (and still 95-99% market cover). Simple everyday features, such as framebuffer objects with multiple render targets and reasonably sized textures are _not_ guaranteed under OpenGL 2.0 -- they _are_ guaranteed under OpenGL 3.0. GL3 is a lot less setup and guesswork than GL2.

Comment: OpenGL 3.0 seems like a good idea. Looks like 3.1 isn't supported on OSX Snow Leopard, so 3.0 is how high I can go.